# Nested Xinerama for xorg.conf

Tags: nvidia, xorg.conf, xinerama

So I have been trying to play around with the idea of nesting an Xinerama set up but with little luck so far. I actually had something similar by mistake about a year ago where one GPU had Xinerama enabled but the second didn't. Thereby one set of screens was seen as one screen while on the other GPU all the screens were separate.

The idea here is to group the screens on the GPU I game on for "ultra wide" peripheral vision style set up while the other screens are separate. However I could make it work if Xinerama was configured per GPU rather than a single instance that clumps everything together because that causes some disparities and issues.

Most the documents I've read are outdated...woefully outdated. Because of this I've really struggled to feel out the correct syntax for this (if it's even possible anymore).

I'm using nVidia 450.66 drivers on Xubuntu 18.04.5 with 5.4.0-48-lowlatency and xserver-xorg 1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1.

The last few tries were based around simply splitting ServerLayout like this.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 1280 1080
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection
```

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout1"
    Screen      1  "Screen1" 1280 0
    Screen      2  "Screen2" 0 56
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection
```

Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any mention of OS & release details.

Comment: Thanks, I was so tired when I posted I completely forgot OS version and kernel.